# Visualizing Dipoles of a Large System with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, physics

I have data file which contains dipole moments and coordinates of dipoles. It has 6 columns, first 3 columns for coordinates and last three for the dipole moments. Also it has data for different time steps let me call these frames.

```
# TIMESTEP 350000 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 406.427474 203.221744 247.500000 
3.852  1.909 22.872       0.00150219       0.00112514      -0.00643028  
3.715  1.854 27.033      -0.00038816      -0.00103382       0.00692119  
3.597  1.860 31.078       0.00048117      -0.00063481       0.00745092  
3.428  1.862 35.215       0.00064382       0.00016735       0.00891062  
3.314  1.930 39.330      -0.00062401       0.00061499       0.00743703  
3.144  1.920 43.449       0.00056694      -0.00012774       0.00743086  
..
.. 
# TIMESTEP 350500 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 406.427474 203.221744 247.500000 
3.852  1.909 22.872       0.00150219       0.00112514      -0.00643028  
3.715  1.854 27.033      -0.00038816      -0.00103382       0.00692119  
3.597  1.860 31.078       0.00048117      -0.00063481       0.00745092  
..
..
```

In each frame there are approximately 200 000 data points, dipoles that I would like to present.
I tried quiver plot but with too many arrows nothing was visible.
Better approach was just to display z component of dipoles - which is most relevant for me- and use heat map with

```
ax.set(xlim=(X.min(),X.max()), ylim=(Y.min(),Y.max() ) )
cmap = plt.get_cmap('seismic')
levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=100).tick_values(-Plim, Plim)
```

Result was something like this:

[image]

But still I am not happy with this approach first it is two dimensional projection second I am losing a lot of information by using MaxNLocator.
Is there a better approach for such a visualization?
It might be helpful if I could reduce the number of dipoles by just calculating local averages i.e. increasing the mesh size. 
Is there a shortcut to calculate local averages, for instance average value of each dipole and its first neighbors, to decrease the number of arrows and make it more visible?

Comment: Would an animated display of the 'frames' be useful? Or does this need to be static? And how many 'frames' are there?

Comment: animated frames would be useful since I would like to see the time evolution of dipoles.There are 400 frames.

Comment: Is the system of dipoles in 2D or 3D? (Spatially)

Comment: It is 3D. The picture above is the sum of all dipoles along y direction

Comment: Unfortunately I think you will have to do some resampling in order to display the full 3D system - but it looks like the system has relatively smooth variation, so a nearest (or next nearest, etc) neighbor averaging should do a pretty good job. I think I can show you how to do that but it might take me a couple days